# Book about Prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

Is there any book that tells theorems about prime numbers with proofs. I know undergraduate calculus. I need a book that explains everything in detail.

Comment: Why not study the Wikipedia-articles ? They are detailed and clear. And in Wikiproofs you can also find the proofs of the most important theorems.

Comment: You may as well go for Hardy and Wright, An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers.  No doubt there is a PDF online somewhere.   If you read German, Landau's Primzahlen should be more than enough.

Comment: Mr. Santos, for what it's worth, I agree wholeheartedly.

Comment: @Peter Maybe you can vouch for the accuracy of Wikipedia articles at the time you read them, but can you vouch for their accuracy 24/7? With a book, Mr. Shameen can hold an author accountable for errors in the book.